# Modify query result during execiution - removing additional "/"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns "Location" and "Location Details"

I want to put them in one column but I get additional `\` in result .

Example

Entry in "Location":  `C:\`

Entry in "Location Details": `\Programe File\`

Result: `C:\\Programe File\`

What I want is `C:\Programe File\`

I want to remove additional `\`

To combine those two column I use `location || location_detail`

Do you have idea how I can do this?

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Also add some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Is it necessary to store backslashes? Can you just store `Programe File` instead? That'd definitely make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` should do

```
select replace(location||location_detail,'\\','\') from YourTable;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22a5d329232c3afe34783cf246450d36)

Answer (score 0):

I use substr option, now query looks like this

```
location || substr(location_detail,2)
```

number 2 take value from second char.